Differences in meanings between similar pronouns (עָלָיו, לוֹ); likewise (יהוּ,- יו-)
Is there someone who discusses the differences between pronoun synonyms?
I'm thinking of two sets as examples, both of which occur within a few pesukim of each other in perek 5 of Shir HaShirim:

5:4 has וּמֵעַי הָמוּ עָלָיו. The phrasing is similar to that in Yirmiyahu 31:20 עַל־כֵּן הָמוּ מֵעַי לוֹ, but one uses עָלָיו and the other uses לוֹ.

5:6 בִּקַּשְׁתִּיהוּ וְלֹא מְצָאתִיהוּ קְרָאתִיו וְלֹא עָנָנִי is very similar to Shir HaShirim 3:1 and 3:2, בִּקַּשְׁתִּיו וְלֹא מְצָאתִיו -- what is the difference between בִּקַּשְׁתִּיהוּ/בִּקַּשְׁתִּיו and מְצָאתִיהוּ/מְצָאתִיו?


I could not find anyone who discusses this and would be grateful for any sources!

Are you looking for parshanut or for a historical explanation?

Either would work. Thanks! :)

Regarding יו- and יהו-, it is important to remember that in ancient Hebrew the letter ו is pronounced w/u. Thus, בקשתיו would be pronounced biqashtiu, quite similar to בקשתיהו - biqashtihu. Compare Shoftim 4:10 ״וירד אביהו אל האשה״.

It's still not clear to me why there would be a switch in the language or what that switch would indicate ... ?

@good_morning I don’t have the data to back this up, but as I understand it, the suffix יהו- is used in a more poetic setting, in the manner that למו is used in place of להם. Perhaps it’s a more archaic form of the word, similar to the way we use archaic terms in poetry (although I’m sure there are many hidden meanings in the difference between them).
